# Php Shell exec didn't run Python file if there are imports like pandas

Tags: python, php, apache, anaconda

I have anaconda to run python,apache server localhost (phpmyadmin), php, with visual studio code. when i use shell exec without pandas is run fine, but when i want to use pandas the shell exec didn't run the python code.

list of imports that prevent python to be executed from php:

1. pandas as pd
2. numpy as np
3. matplotdip.pyplot as plt
4. from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
5. from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
6. from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score,hamming_loss,classification_report

**test.py**

```
import sys
import json
# import pandas as pd
# from pandas import json_normalize

import os
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors as mpl
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score,hamming_loss,classification_report


print("Hello world has been called")
```

Is there something need to be done? i really need the imports for python